# Moving row cell to column if index is same

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with the below example

```
Type   | date
Apple  |01/01/2021
Apple  |10/02/2021
Orange |05/01/2021
Orange |20/20/2020
```

Is there any easiest way transform the data as below?

```
Type  | Date
Apple | 01/01/2020 | 10/20/2021
Orange| 05/01/2020 | 20/20/2020
```

The stack function does not match my requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could group by "type", collect the "date" values and make a new dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'type':['Apple','Apple','Orange','Orange'], 'date':['01/01/2021','10/02/2021','05/01/2021','20/20/2020']})

d = {}
for fruit, group in df.groupby('type'):
    d[fruit] =  group.date.values

pd.DataFrame(d).T

                 0           1
Apple   01/01/2021  10/02/2021
Orange  05/01/2021  20/20/2020
```